# build finished but app is not running - android

Tags: android, build.gradle

app is not running neither on emulator nor on real device. I do not understand the reason. this is my build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ge.mobility.anako.parser"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: What do you get in your logs?

Comment: DId you check the run board to see if app is starting?

Comment: 3:57:54 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
3:58:05 PM Gradle build finished in 11s 497ms

Comment: check in your manifest whether there is any launcher activity available or not

Comment: what studio and gradle version you are using ?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1 Gradle Version 2.8

Comment: Check launch options, sometimes that could be a problem.

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 3):

For me after I update compileSdkVersion to 31 and add my starting activity android:exported="false" this happend. exported=true resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it happens due to very large images. If you have such images, try to shrink'em and your app should run.

I'm using [this online tool](https://tinypng.com) to shrink PNGs. It will shrink your image, while keeping it's quality.

Good luck!

Comment: If you find it helpful - I wrote a [command-line tool for shrinking PNGs via tinypng.com](https://github.com/RanyAlbegWein/Tinypng). Use it as if you wrote it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidate caches and restart worked for me.

Comment: The only time this suggestion did anything at all!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added launch options end if i delete, run normaly

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough none of the suggestions above worked for me. But it was resolved after I deleted my emulator's virtual image and recreated it.